# Visual Studio 2010 Cannot start a web browser when run as administrator

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I run VS2010 as admin I can't open the external web browser for things like help, links from the Extensions manager etc.  When not in admin mode everything is fine.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you have installed with other user insted of admin,

Just install it again/ or start repair, That may help,

Select install for all users, instead of "only me" if asked.

I hope this may solve,

Else just uninstall and re-install.

take care,